# Pandas Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with YYYY-MM as data, however I want to find the mean of the temperature for the year, therefore I need to add up the 12 months in a year, and find the summary. How do I do that using Pandas?

An example of my data: (I have more than a year dataset, tried to reshape them, but it doesn't seem to work)

[image: Example of dataset]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your actual data, not an image of your data. So that your example is a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are we to assume that your data is only for one single year (1982), and has all months complete (1982-01..1982-12)? The solution here is not at all general, and only works for your specific case.

Comment: Maybe there's a misunderstanding. If you read from my post, I did try to reshape them and get the initial coding, but there's an error. not expecting free code writing but more of guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Ket us do string slice then `groupby` + `sum`

```
s=df.groupby(df['month'].str[:4]).sum()
```

Comment: Oh that's awesome and indeed solve my problem! Thanks for the help and prompt reply.